# How can I manage files on Ubuntu server VM on Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I have deployed a LAMP stack to a virtual machine in Azure, by following this tutorial: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lamp-stack
It's all up and running. However, I can't figure out how to manage the files on the server, and/or copy/upload files to the server.

I can ssh into the VM using the Azure Cloud shell, but I don't seem to have access to my local files if I do it that way. So I installed the Azure CLI on my local machine but when I try to open an ssh session to the server I get 'permission denied (publickey)'.

I've looked into secure copy - scp - and have tried connecting to the server with Putty and WinSCP, but the error that I get is 'No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)'

I'm new to Apache and just can't figure out how to list the files on the server or manage them at all...

Comment: The search term for this is "deployment", that should give you hints.

Comment: That's not actually much helpful without a bit more clarification

Comment: Getting your code onto the machine is called deployment. Using that search term should help you find documentation. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using puTTY and WinSCP. Whereas before I had been using the Azure Cloudshell commands to create the VM and generate the ssh keys - so I could connect to the VM using Cloudshell but since I didn't know where the auto-generated keys were stored, I couldn't connect on my local machine.

My solution was to create the VM through the Azure portal UI interface. I used puTTYgen to generate ssh key pairs on my local machine, then I input the public key into the Azure UI when creating the VM. Once the VM was provisioned in Azure, I could connect to it using puTTY and install LAMP and any other command-line stuff that way.

I also used WinSCP to copy the files to where I wanted - I could have done it command-line with scp, but I'm a visual person and it was useful to be able to see the directory structure that had been created. So a combination of the two worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the secure copy "scp", there is one point you should pay attention to. If you create the Azure VM with setting the user as azureuser, and then you just can use the command `scp /path/file azureuser@domainName:/home/azureuser/filename` to copy the file. Because you just have the permission of the user "azureuser" so that you just can copy the file from outside to the vm directory `/home/azureuser` no matter you use a password or the ssh public key.

**Update**

If you create the Azure VM with ssh public key, you need to store the key in where you want to connect the VM. For example, you want to connect to the VM in local Windows 10. The key should be stored in the directory "`C:\Users\charlesx\.ssh`". So that you can connect to the VM, also with scp command.

Comment: I tried that by running the Azure CLI locally on my machine, but seemed like access to the server was denied - would I need to enable remote login?

Comment: If you can ssh into the VM, you can also scp file to it. If you can give mo details about the error you got?

Comment: I updated the question to give more info re. ssh - is ok using cloud CLI but not Locally.

Comment: If you use the public ssh key, you should store the key in the right way. And it should be stored there where you want to use. For example, it also should be stored in your local machine.